# Covering relation over functions

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

F is a group that includes all functions from N to N
K is relation over F.
For f,g ∈ F: (f,g) ∈ K iff ∀ n∈N, f(n)≤g(n).

Obviously K is Partially ordered set and not Total Order.

My problem is with proving that:
for ∀ f∈F ∃ g ∈ F that covers f.
and that for ∀ f∈F there is more than one g that covers f.

Can anyone help me to prove this?
Thanks :)

Comment: You could just delete the question instead. The original post is still in the edit history.

Comment: for some reason it won't let me to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Given $f\in F$, consider the following functions: for each $m\in\Bbb N$ let $g_m\in F$ be defined by

$$g_m(k)=\begin{cases}
f(k),&\text{if }k\ne m\\
f(k)+1,&\text{if }k=m\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: i can understand why g(k)=f(k)+1 covers f.
but why is the other one covers f?

Comment: @ddodd: $g(k)$ is just one of the function values: it’s not in $F$, so it can’t cover $f$. But each of the functions $g_m$ does cover $f$, though you will have to explain why this is true.

Comment: @brian-m-scott:let g_m be the function you defiend.

f≤g_m and f≠g_m.

let h∈F h≠f and h≠g,if k=m g(k)=f(k)+1 and because F is from $N to $N there can't be f(k)≤h(k)≤g_m(k).


is that good?i still can't manage to do the other side...

Comment: @ddodd: It could be stated a little better, but yes, it’s fine. I’m not sure what you mean by ‘the other side’: the functions $g_m$ give you infinitely many different functions covering $f$.

Comment: the other side is when k≠m

Comment: @ddodd: Same argument. For each $k$ we have $f(k)\le h(k)\le g_m(k)$ by hypothesis. If $k\ne m$, then $f(k)=g_m(k)$, so $h(k)=f(k)$. If $k=m$, then $g_m(k)=f(k)+1$, so either $h(k)=f(k)$, in which case $h=f$, or $h(k)=g_m(k)$, in which case $h=g_m$.

Comment: Is it ok to say that if h(k)=f(k) then h=f?

Comment: @ddodd: Only if $k=m$. You first show that $h(k)=f(k)$ whenever $k\ne m$. Then you observe that $h(m)$ is either $f(m)$, in which case $h(k)=f(k)$ for all $k$ and therefore $h=f$, or $h(m)=f(m)+1=g_m(m)$, in which case $h(k)=g_m(k)$ for all $k$ and therefore $h=g_m$.

Comment: Also is it ok to say that by defining g_m for every m∈N then i proved that there are infinite functions that covers f?

Comment: @ddodd: Sure: each $g_m$ covers $f$, and $g_m\ne g_n$ whenever $m\ne n$, so the functions $g_m$ are all distinct.

Comment: @ddodd: You’re welcome.